# Narrower types for pytest fixtures that perform actions without returning objects?

Tags: python, types, pytest, mypy

Consider a fixture like

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_database(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch) -> None:
    ...
```

And it's use in a test

```py
def test_with_mock_database(mock_database: None) -> None:
    ...
```

What is the type of `mock_database` in the test argument? It appears to actually be just a `None` at runtime, but this makes it a little hard to narrow down, if I want to distinguish between e.g. a `SetupFixture` and a `TeardownFixture`, since there's no such thing as a class Fixture(None), and casting hacks like

```py
class _FixtureType:
    pass

FixtureType = cast(_FixtureType, None)

@pytest.fixture
def mock_database(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch) -> FixtureType:
    ...
```

Kind of break, because I have to `return` *something* now.

Are there other, more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can *visually* distinguish the fixtures by using a `typing.TypeAlias`. Whether you can navigate effectively through the code base or lint properly is another issue.

```py
"""my_project_types.py"""
import typing as t

# Note: `TypeAlias` is not suitable for `is` comparisons (don't write `if my_value is SetupFixture`)
SetupFixture: t.TypeAlias = None
```

```py
from my_project_types import SetupFixture

@pytest.fixture
def mock_database(monkeypatch: MonkeyPatch) -> SetupFixture:
    """No explicit return or yield required here"""
```

```py
from my_project_types import SetupFixture

def test_with_mock_database(mock_database: SetupFixture) -> None:
    ...
```